# Passing the context to a function call

Tags: javascript

Can anyone, please, explain why the following call:

```
f = () => this;
f.call({});
```

returns, in Firebug, the window global context? Shouldn't it return the passed {} empty context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Arrow functions do not have their own this", instead, [Arrow functions establish "this" based on the scope the Arrow function is defined within.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#call_apply_and_bind)

Comment: Indeed, the call: f = function() {return this}; f.call({}); works as expected. Thank you!